# Can we dissolve salts with higher lattice enthalpy by providing heat?

Tags: thermodynamics

It is well-known that

> A salt with a higher lattice energy will not dissolve at all, because then $\Delta_{\text{sol}}H^\ominus$ will be negative.

So, the reaction should be endothermic, right? My question is:

**If then we provide heat to the reaction, then we should be able to dissolve such salts. Is this true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat itself it just indirect factor. It is temperature what determines the shift of solubility products. If the dissolution is endothermic process, the salt [solubility product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_equilibrium) would increase with higher temperature.

But if the solubility product is still small even at high temperature, like e.g. $\pu{e-16}$ instead of $\pu{e-20}$, then only a tiny extra salt amount would dissolve when heated.

The effective result depends on the particular case. The typical cases where significant solubility increase is observed are  potassium salts  $\ce{KNO3, KClO3, KClO4}$. But they have limited solubility even at low temperature - see the [solubility table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table#P).

Generally, the dependence of an equlibrium constant of a reaction, including dissolving/precipitation process, is described by [van't Hoff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation#Equation)

> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}T} \ln K_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{\Delta H^\ominus}{RT^2}$$

For solubility products, being equlibrium constants, is valid the following reaction:

$$\Delta G^{\circ}_\mathrm{dis} = \Delta H^{\circ}_\mathrm{dis}  - T \Delta S^{\circ}_\mathrm{dis} = RT \ln K_\mathrm{sp}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why heat is not a factor? Negative $\Delta H$ implies we need to supply energy, which we can, in the form of heat.

Comment: Okay, one final time: is this reasoning correct? *Since by Hess' Law, $\Delta_{\text{sol}}H^\ominus =\Delta_{\text{lattice}}H^\ominus+\Delta_{\text{hyd}}H^\ominus$. Therefore, if $\Delta_{\text{lattice}}H^\ominus$ is big enough, $\Delta_{\text{sol}}H^\ominus$ will be largely negative, and the salt may not dissolve at all.* Can this be improved upon more?

Comment: Heat is only a factor as it is needed to increase temperature, or to keep temperature during the endothermic process. Negative $\Delta H$ means the equilibrium constant increases with increased temperature. But as the process of practically insoluble salts causes negligible heat consumption, it does not play much role.

Comment: For c = a + b, saying if a is big enough, c is largely negative does not make sense. Note that for the solibility product value, the decisive is the value of the Gibbs energy of dissolution, so the entropy change can affect the raw value of the enthalpy.

Comment: So, what's the proper reasoning?

Comment: Try to think about any of your question for some time, before asking. It gives you more than if you get the answer by a cheap, easy and fast way.

Comment: Can you please, as the last time, let me know the proper reason for saying that salts with higher lattice enthalpy may not dissolve at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118308/discussion-between-poutnik-and-ultralegend5385).

Comment: The point is, my book simply says that without any reason, and I want to conform my guesses.